# How do I search the leaves of a tree where each node could have more than two children?

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to search the leaves of a tree data structure for a target value. 
My function looks like this:

```
def searchLeaves(self, target): #DFS
        if len(self.children == 0): #is a leaf
            if self.data == target:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else: 
            for x in self.children:
                return x.searchLeaves(target)
```

However, my problem is in the else statement. If it were a binary tree, I could do

```
else:
    return x.leftchild.searchLeaves(target) or x.rightchild.searchleaves(target)
```

In order to consolidate the combinations of falses and trues that the base case will produce. How could I apply this "or" logical operator to an undetermined amount of children?

Comment: This seems more about the particulars to python, so I think it belongs on stack overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
else:
    return any(x.searchLeaves(target) for x in self.children)
```

This is equivalent to this:

```
else:
    for x in self.children:
        if x.searchLeaves(target):
             return True
    return False
```

Comment: This works for any N-ary tree. When the asker mentioned "left or right" that is a specific optimization of this general-purpose algorithm. What will really bake his noodle is "how do you perform an in-order traversal of an N-ary tree where N is greater than 2?"

Comment: @Snowman what does in-order mean in a tree with more than two children. for a tree with four children it's after two or after the first, what if there are three children?